# Nexus 4 not recognised in Ubuntu 12.04 for file transfer

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, nexus-4

nexus 4 from an Ubuntu 12.04 OS . i tried downloading mtp packages and installing them but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may select "Camera (PTP)" as connection type, which at least allows you to transfer image files. MTP does not work for me either on a stock Ubuntu 12.04.

Alternatively you can install an app like "File Expert Manager Explorer" or "WiFi File Explorer PRO". They allow for wireless transfer of files.

Finally it is possible to transfer files with `adb` (part of Android SDK package).
See [this](http://log.amitshah.net/2012/05/using-adb-to-copy-files-to-from-your-android-device/) for details.